# How do I get the active page URL in my skin?

Tags: dotnetnuke

In my DNN skin, I know I can use this code to display the active page URL:

`<%= NavigateUrl(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.Url) %>`

But that shows the absolute URL which includes the domain. I want to show the **relative** URL. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Request.RawUrl

```
<%= Request.RawUrl %>
```

If you have a url like `www.yoursite.nl/page1/page2` it will give you `/page1/page2`